# Atomic addition to floating point values in OpenCL for NVIDIA GPUs?

Tags: floating-point, opencl, nvidia, gpgpu, gpu-atomics

The OpenCL 3.0 specification [does not seem to have](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/3.0-unified/html/OpenCL_C.html#C11-spec) intrinsics/builtins for atomic addition to floating-point values, only for integral values (and that seems to have been the case in OpenCL 1.x and 2.x as well). CUDA, however, [has offered](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) floating-point atomics for a while now:

```
float  atomicAdd(float*  address, float  val); // since Fermi
double atomicAdd(double* address, double val); // since Pascal
__half atomicAdd(__half *address, __half val); // ?
```

Naturally, any straightforward atomic operation can be simulated with compare-and-exchange, and this *is* available in OpenCL. But my questions are:

1. Does NVIDIA expose floating-point atomics in OpenCL somehow? e.g. via a vendor extension? using pragmas? implicitly?
2. Is there a more efficient mechanism than simulation with compare-exchange, which I could consider as a substitute for floating-point atomics? For NVIDIA GPUs or generally?

Comment: I don't know about nvidia's hardware, but the way to solve this in OpenCL is [to use atomic compare-exchange at the byte level](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31863587/48660) i.e. using integer atomics on the data at the atomic memory location.

Comment: @pmdj: Yes, I specifically mentioned that. But - this would be much slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @ProjectPhysX implied in their answer, when you compile OpenCL with NVIDIA's driver, it accepts [inline PTX assembly](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/inline-ptx-assembly/index.html) (which is of course not at all part of OpenCL nor a recognized vendor extension). This lets you basically do anything CUDA offers you - in OpenCL; and that includes atomically adding to floating point values.

So, here are wrapper functions for atomically adding to single-precision (32-bit) floating point values in global and in local memory:

```opencl
float atomic_add_float_global(__global float* p, float val)
{
    float prev;
    asm volatile(
        "atom.global.add.f32 %0, [%1], %2;" 
        : "=f"(prev) 
        : "l"(p) , "f"(val) 
        : "memory" 
    );
    return prev;
}

float atomic_add_float_local(__local float* p, float val)
{
    float prev;
    // Remember "local" in OpenCL means the same as "shared" in CUDA.
    asm volatile(
        "atom.shared.add.f32 %0, [%1], %2;"
        : "=f"(prev) 
        : "l"(p) , "f"(val) 
        : "memory" 
    );
    return prev;
}
```

One could also perhaps tweak this by checking whether the OpenCL driver is NVIDIA's, in which case the inline assembly is used, or non-NVIDIA, in which the atomic-compare-exchange implementation is used.

Answer (score 3):

Native foating-point atomics are a much desired extension for OpenCL 3.0. As of right now, they are still not available.

1. The only possible way would be to use [inline PTX](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html).
2. No. The [implementation with atomic compare-exchange for FP32 and FP64](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70822133/9178992) is currently state-of-the-art and there is no known better way.

UPDATE June 2022: [Floating-point atomics are being added to the OpenCL 3.0 standard](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Docs/blob/main/extensions/cl_ext_float_atomics.asciidoc) but adoption by hardware vendors might still take some time.

Comment: See my answer regarding jumping the gun on NVIDIA hardware at least. And thanks for the update!